# Why does `nohup top` cut the output lines?

Tags: top, nohup

I want to use `nohup` to periodically log the output of `top` (every 15s). For that, I log into the server with SSH, carry out the following command, and log out again:

```
nohup top -b -c -d15 &
```

The `-c` flag provides additional information about the command, but in the generated `nohup.out` file, this information is cut to 82 characters.

So instead of output like this:

```
10484 daemon   20   0 68924 5556 2292 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.06 /opt/CollabNet_Subversion/bin/httpd -D csvn_installed -k start
```

... in `nohup.out` it looks like this:

```
10484 daemon   20   0 68924 5556 2292 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.06 /opt/CollabNet_Subv
```

How can I prevent `nohup` from trimming the results of `top`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the output width `top` should use, with the `-w` parameter (up to a maximum of 512 columns):

```
nohup top -b -c -d15 -w512 &
```

If your version of `top` doesn't support `-w`, the same effect can be achieved using the `COLUMNS` environment variable:

```
COLUMNS=512 nohup top -b -c -d15 &
```

As explained by [schily](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/120884/schily), since `top` isn't outputting to a terminal in this case, it can't determine the terminal width to use and falls back to a safe default.

Comment: top: unknown argument 'w' (top: procps version 3.2.8)

Comment: Ah yes, you can use `COLUMNS` instead.

Comment: `COLUMNS=512` works, but the downside is that now *all* lines in the `nohup.out` file are filled up with spaces to 512 characters length!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot unless there is an explicit way to tell your specific `top` version which output with it should use. The `top` implementation I am aware of does not permit to specify the output width.

This is  because `nohup` causes the `top` program to be run with a plain file as `stdout` instead of a terminal.

For this reason, `top` cannot retrieve the tty width and falls back to the standard 80 columns.